# Implications in Boltzmann's wiki article

Tags: implication

Found something odd while reading [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludwig_Boltzmann#Childhood_and_education).

> When Boltzmann was 15 his father died.

The way it's phrased, it sort of implies that his father died *because* Boltzmann was 15. Unless I'm reading into it too much.

Comment: You think too much. The implication is not there.

Comment: Just an odd way to write it then?

Comment: If we wanted say that Boltzmann's father died because Boltzmann became 15 we'd say "Because Boltzmann became 15 his father died."

Comment: "When Boltzmann became 15 his father died." would imply that Boltzmann's father died shortly after Boltzmann's 15th birthday, not because of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic "meaning" of a *when* clause is temporal location, not causation. Ordinarily an inference of causation will be triggered only if the *when* clause expresses an event prior to the event in the main clause; but *Boltzmann was 15* is a continuing state in which the father's death is temporally embedded. And even if the *when* clause were an event (*When Boltzmann turned 15*, for instance), we would infer causation only if some causal link were present either in our ordinary knowledge of the world or in the discourse context.

> The elder Boltzmann had been gravely ill, but kept working to assure his family the income which would support his son's academic advancement; when Boltzmann turned 15 and earned admission to the Linzer Realgymnasium, his father allowed himself to die.<sup>†</sup>

And the phrasing is not at all odd: it's the most natural and unambiguous way to express the thought.

> When he was 15 Boltzmann's father died *and*
> Boltzmann's father died when he was 15 *are at least momentarily ambiguous: on first encountering either of these we take* he *to refer to the head of the noun phrase, the* father, *not to* Boltzmann, *the determiner.*
>
> His father died when Boltzmann was 15 *is unambiguous but requires extra parsing because the referent of* his *is postponed*.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>I made that up.</sub>